# skip header row when parsing .csv file

Tags: .net, csv, streamreader

I’m using a StreamReader object to provide source data for the LinqtoCSV library. Something like this…

```
CsvFileDescription fileDescription = new CsvFileDescription() 
{ 
            SeparatorChar = ';', 
            MaximumNbrExceptions = 20,                 
};  
        CsvContext context = new CsvContext();           
        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(file.Data); 
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream); 
        rows = context.Read<T>(reader, fileDescription);
```

I’m processing csv files which have an extra semi colon in the header row e.g.

```
Header1; Header2;Header3;
```

This triggers errors because the CSVtoLinQ library is expecting 4 header names instead of 3. I can read selected rows into an IEnumerable object, but I can’t directly manipulate the contents of the StreamReader object.  I’d prefer to continue with the combination of StreamReader/LinqtoCSV as it provides a lot of validation functionality, but because of  the file header issue I need to look at alternatives.

Are there other csv import libraries that provide (i) field based validation when parsing a file (ii) a means of skipping the header row?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a method that opens the file, checks the header/fixes it, then saves to a new file which now ready for the existing process.

Comment: I ended up editing the byte stream (the file.data object in the example)

e.g. 

System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
string csvfile = enc.GetString(newFile.Data);
string csvfilenew= csvfile.Replace("header3;", "header3;dummyfieldname");
newFile.Data = enc.GetBytes(csvfilenew);

I'll probably add some code to verify the encoding of the file etc. but for now it seems to work. 

Providing a dummy field name, with a nullable string column definition, prevents linqtocsv from triggering an exception.